# Why is test MSE so low on basic linear model but high on advanced LASSO model? (with hopefully less variance)

Tags: r, linear-regression, prediction, training-data, lasso-regression

I am performing regression on a Pokémon dataset(https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/rounakbanik/pokemon) trying to predict HP of a Pokémon with a selection of features. The features used in the model have been selected using different methods: Best subset selection, lasso with random lambda value and lasso with cross-validated lambda value. However, for the best subset selection I had to remove a feature ("classfication") in order to make it work as my training and validation set did not contain the same levels of "classfication", having a lot of different levels (Pokémon types).  Now, when comparing all methods with my test set on the MSE, it seems as if the LASSO and cross-validated LASSO have a way larger MSE and i do not get why that is the case. I think it may be because of the removal of "classfication". How can i still include this in my best subset selection model? Additionally, I think it has to be something else as well, as a linear model including all variables also has a very low MSE, lower than the LASSO models. I will provide the code below and am curious how this is possible and can possibly be solved. Thanks in advance.

```
#load the generate formulas function
source("generate_formulas.R")

#remove "classification" variable from training and validation set in order to
#run best subset selection

df_train <- df_train %>%
  select(-classfication)

df_valid <- df_valid %>% 
  select(-classfication)

#Retrieve all variable names for the generation of all possible formulas (except for outcome variable "HP")
x_vars <- colnames(df_train)
x_vars <- x_vars[x_vars != "hp"]

#Function to obtain the mse on the validation dataset 
#for predictions from a linear model
lm_mse <- function(formula, train_data, valid_data) {
  y_name <- as.character(formula)[2]
  y_true <- valid_data[[y_name]]
  
  lm_fit <- lm(formula, train_data)
  y_pred <- predict(lm_fit, newdata = valid_data)
  
  mean((y_true - y_pred)^2)
}


#Create set of formulas with 3 predictors
formulas_pred_3 <- generate_formulas(p = 3, x_vars = x_vars, y_var = "hp")

# Initialize variables for best formula and best MSE
best_formula <- ""
best_mse <- Inf

# For loop over each formula and calculate the MSE
for (formula in formulas_pred_3) {
  model <- lm(as.formula(formula), data = df_train)
  prediction <- predict(model, newdata = df_valid)
  mse <- mean((df_valid$hp - prediction)^2)

  # Check if current MSE is lower than the previous best MSE
  if (mse < best_mse) {
    best_mse <- mse
    best_formula <- formula
  }
}

# Print the best formula and MSE
cat("Best formula with 3 predictors:", best_formula, "\n")
cat("Best MSE:", best_mse, "\n")
```

**And now for the comparison based on MSE:**

```
#1) Linear regression
#2) Best subset model selection
#3) LASSO with random lambda (25)
#4) Lasso with cross-validated lambda

# create this new training dataset and the test dataset
train_data <- bind_rows(df_train, df_valid)
x_test <- model.matrix(hp ~ ., data = df_test)[, -1]

# generate predictions from the models
#1) Predictions of HP from a linear model containing ALL Variables
y_pred_lm <- predict(lm(hp ~ ., data = train_data), newdata = df_test)


#2) Predictions of HP from a linear model after subset selection
y_pred_subset <- predict(lm(hp ~ base_total + defense + speed, data = train_data),
                      newdata = df_test)

#3) LASSO with random lambda of 25
#For this lasso model we use the model.matrix x_train_and_val from earlier on
y_pred_las  <- predict(result_train_and_val, s = 25, newx = x_test, type = "coefficients")

#4) Lasso with 15 folds cross- validated lambda of 0.05116354 (determined earlier on)
y_pred_cv_las <- predict(LASSO_model, s = best_lambda, newx = x_test, type = "coefficients")

#define function to retrieve MSE
mse <- function(y_true, y_pred) {
  mean((y_true - y_pred)^2)
}

# Calculate MSEs of all models
mses <- c(
  mse(df_test$hp, y_pred_lm),
  mse(df_test$hp, y_pred_subset),
  mse(df_test$hp, y_pred_las),
  mse(df_test$hp, y_pred_cv_las)
)

# Create a plot
tibble(Method = as_factor(c("linear model", "subset linear model", "lasso (λ = 25)", "Cross-validated lasso (λ = 0.05)")), MSE = mses) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Method, y = MSE, fill = Method)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", col = "black") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  labs(title = "Comparison of test set MSE for different prediction methods") +
  scale_fill_viridis_d() # different colour scale
```

[Comparison of test set MSE for different prediction methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWlGP.png)